# JQuery Promise Video Play. promise.then not a function

Tags: jquery, promise

I am using jQuery.YoutubeBackground.js to play a background video on my site. https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var promise = $('#homevideo').YTPlayer({
            fitToBackground: true,
            videoId: '123456', // YouTube video ID
            mute: false, // Change to true to mute music
            playerVars: {
                    modestbranding: 0,
                    autoplay: 1,
                    controls: 0,
                    showinfo: 0,
                    branding: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                    autohide: 0
            },
            callback: function() {

            }        
    });
});
```

I am trying to add promise to my code.

```
if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(_ => {
        console.log("Autoplay started!");
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Autoplay Not started!");
    });
}
```

I am receiving the error Uncaught TypeError: promise.then is not a function. I believe it may have to do with the placement of the `if (promise !== undefined)` section?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that `YTPlayer` returns a promise?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure.

Comment: Then why are you using it like it would? O.o Check the documentation on how to use the `YTPlayer` instance.

Comment: Do you not get a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `YTPlayer` function doesn't return a promise as you can see [here](https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground/blob/dbdfa723e09c605349dd441dced7ef3e46388dff/src/jquery.youtubebackground.js#L317/). If you wan't to run something after it is initialized you can write that logic in the callback in the options object:

```
$('#homevideo').YTPlayer({
  fitToBackground: true,
  videoId: 'FlsCjmMhFmw',
  mute: false,
  playerVars: {
    modestbranding: 0,
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    branding: 0,
    rel: 0,
    autohide: 0
  },
  callback: function() {
    console.log("Autoplay started!");
  }        
});
```